# How to use PowerShell get the start up account of a process?

Tags: security, powershell, authentication, process, runas

On windows, I can use `runas` to run an application as another account (not the one your are logged in at the moment) like this:

```
runas /netonly /user:some_domain\account "utility.exe"
```

How can I get this `some_domain\account` from PowerShell? I've checked Get-Process and `win32_process` WMI class but didn't find anything useful.

---

#### Update

Re @briantist's answer:
I'm a little confused about the result from @briantist's answer. I logged on to my computer using a local account (my computer is not in a domain) and `runas` the utility (SQL Server management studio aka SSMS here) as a domain account. When I run the script that @briantist provided, the result just shows me that SSMS is running on my local account not the domain account. But in SSMS I can use a function `suser_sname()` to ask the server who am i and the result is `some_domain\account`. It's a little weird to me. Is this by design or am I wrong some where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get-process has an -IncludeUserName switch:

```
get-process -IncludeUserName
```

Specifically for utility.exe:

```
get-process utility -IncludeUserName
```

Comment: I've tried and found this only works on PowerShell 4.0. Is there a way to get this info in PowerShell 3.0?

Comment: Briantist's answer will work pre v4. As will my comment to it.

Answer (score 1):

Tony Hinkle's answer (+1) is great, and very simple, but it does require elevation.

To do this as a non-privileged user, you can use CIM:

```powershell
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name='utility.exe'" | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName GetOwner
```

If you can elevate, I do recommend the other answer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with getting a CIM Instance per se, but it isn't really required. ***(gwmi win32_process -filter "name='utility.exe'").GetOwner().User***

Comment: Thanks @EBGreen and briantist. I'm updated my question and added more details. Could you help to take a look?

Comment: I just ran powershell with one account, used runas to run notepad as a different account, then used the above command and saw that it was running as the second account. I wonder if the /netonly parameter may have something to do with it.

Comment: Yep, /netonly causes what you are seeing. Try it without that parameter.